# Flutter : can't add FFShamel font

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

I'm trying to add this font (FF Shamel Family Sans One) to my project but the flutter's default font still active

this is my font in pub

```
fonts:
    - family: FFShamelFamily
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/ArbFONTS-FFShamelFamily-SansOneBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/ArbFONTS-FFShamelFamily-SansOneBook.ttf
```

and in main

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'FFShamelFamily',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
```

[image]

can anyone tell me where is the wrong !!!

Comment: please check indentation in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: what the meaning of indentation please ?

Comment: pubspec.yaml is indent sensitive. Indentation means the gap before the line starts. You will find that there is more gap in the start as you go down.

Comment: I looked on it and i found it like you implement in your answer

Comment: use `weight` as I have showed in the below answer.

Comment: I will try it now and back for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fonts:
  - family: FFShamelFamily
    fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/ArbFONTS-FFShamelFamily-SansOneBold.ttf
      weight: 700
    - asset: assets/fonts/ArbFONTS-FFShamelFamily-SansOneBook.ttf
```

Comment: Once you make changes, stop the app completely. Then restart it. It should work

Comment: sorry , but the same problem still found , I stop the app completely and do flutter clean also

Comment: can you please share screenshot of your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: i did it in the question , kindly review it

Comment: everything looks perfect. Can you also share the error message